# Run script as root immediately after login to gui

Tags: hard-drive, login, spindown

Because of some reason, my harddrives spin up after I log in to my account.

In rc.local is a `hdparm -y /dev/sda` (sda is my Data Raid that is never mounted in linux, only used for video cutting in windows) that spins down my hdds directly on boot time.

problem: as soon as I log in they spin up again; so I want to run this command again (needing root rights for that) directly after log in to unity. (ubuntu 15.10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to make sure that you can run that command with `sudo` without needing a password. So, you can do that in the `sudoers` file:

```
sudo visudo
```

In this file, you should see a line that looks like:

```
YOURUSERNAME ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

If not, that's okay, don't worry about it too much. You're in the `sudoers` group at the group rule is in there too. In order to execute `hdparm` without a password, you just need to add a rule for it:

```
YOURUSERNAME ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/hdparm
```

If that rule is at the very end, you can execute that program without a password. Yay!

Then, just add a custom startup application in the "Startup Applications" menu:

```
sudo hdparm -y /dev/sda
```

Because you don't need a password for it, it will execute just fine each time you log-in.

If you would like to run this script automatically when you resume from a suspend/sleep, you need to create a another script for it:

```
sudo YOURTEXTEDITOR HERE /lib/systemd/system-sleep/hdparm-resume.sh
```

And use the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    exit 0
    ;;
  post/*)
    sudo hdparm -y /dev/sda
    exit 0
    ;;
esac
```

Finally, to make sure it can be executed:

```
sudo chmod a+x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/hdparm-resume.sh
```

Comment: I should clarify. If you **do** see the `YOUR USERNAME ALL = (ALL) ALL` line, you need to put the rule **after** that line to make sure it's applied.

Comment: @TheBrownOne is there a way to run the script on "re login" after resume?

Comment: @Tobi Yes, I will update my answer now to include this.

Comment: The answer is updated. This will work in 15.10 if you are still using `systemd`. However, if you switched back from `systemd` to `upstart`, I'll have to edit again :P