# How to run script on startup with root

Tags: bash, scripts, cron, root, autostart

I have my little script to start an application and do some more things on my Ubuntu 16.04 which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
./ROC-smi/rocm-smi -d 1 --setfan 90
./ROC-smi/rocm-smi -d 0 --setfan 90
./ROC-smi/rocm-smi -d 2 --setfan 110
./ROC-smi/rocm-smi -d 3 --setfan 110
./ROC-smi/rocm-smi -d 4 --setfan 110
cd teamredminer-v0.4.1-linux
/usr/bin/screen -dm ./teamredminer --algo=cnr --url=*** --user=*** --pass=*** --watchdog_script
```

I want to autostart it with sudo. I tried rc.local with:

```
sh /path/to/my/script.sh
exit 0
```

I also tried using crontab with:

```
@reboot /path/to/my/script.sh
```

nothing worked, rc.local didn't show any errors when I tested it with 
`sudo /etc/init.d/rc.local start`, but when I type `sudo screen -xr` or `screen -ls` or `sudo screen -ls`, I always got a message that there's no screen to attach.

Comment: Why do you want to start this as root? If you want a screen session that your user can use, you need it to be running as your user.

Answer (score 0):

I see there might be two problems with what you're doing.

### 1. Check your scrip has permission to run

Just chmod-it like

```bsh
    chmod +x /path/to/my/script.sh
    chmod +x /path/to/ROC-smi/rocm-smi
```

Otherwise it won't run.

### 2. Fix wrong paths

When you have `./ROC-smi/rocm-smi` you're telling bash to run `ROC-smi/rocm-smi` from the path you're calling the script, not from where the script is located. This means that if you call the script from `/root`, bash will look for `/root/ROC-smi/rocm-smi` and not for `/path/to/my/script/ROC-smi/rocm-smi`.

The most straightforward solution is

```bsh
    #!/bin/bash
    /absolute/path/to/ROC-smi/rocm-smi -d 1 --setfan 90
    /absolute/path/to/ROC-smi/rocm-smi -d 0 --setfan 90
    /absolute/path/to/ROC-smi/rocm-smi -d 2 --setfan 110
    /absolute/path/to/ROC-smi/rocm-smi -d 3 --setfan 110
    /absolute/path/to/ROC-smi/rocm-smi -d 4 --setfan 110
    cd /absolute/path/to/teamredminer-v0.4.1-linux
    /usr/bin/screen -dm ./teamredminer --algo=cnr --url=*** --user=*** --pass=*** --watchdog_script
```

However, if that script can run from anywhere, this quick patch will do as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43823575/running-script-with-relative-paths-from-another-directory)

```bsh
    #!/bin/bash
    scriptdir="$(dirname "$0")"
    cd $scriptdir"
    ROC-smi/rocm-smi -d 1 --setfan 90
    ...
```

Now, `$0` is unreliable ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659689/referring-to-a-file-relative-to-executing-script)) so perhaps you want to try `cd "${BASH_SOURCE%/*}"` instead. I would try

```bsh
    #!/bin/bash
    cd ${BASH_SOURCE%/*}
    ROC-smi/rocm-smi -d 1 --setfan 90
    ROC-smi/rocm-smi -d 0 --setfan 90
    ROC-smi/rocm-smi -d 2 --setfan 110
    ROC-smi/rocm-smi -d 3 --setfan 110
    ROC-smi/rocm-smi -d 4 --setfan 110
    cd /absolute/path/to/teamredminer-v0.4.1-linux
    /usr/bin/screen -dm ./teamredminer --algo=cnr --url=*** --user=*** --pass=*** --watchdog_script
```

Comment: ok, both my scripts were working when im using them throught terminal. I fix all paths to absolute paths like you said, and still it dont work. When i tested it a got that message [ ok ] Starting rc.local (via systemctl): rc.local.service.

Comment: Okay... Well, then it seems to be working pretty much OK once X server is up and running. AFAIK `rc.local` and cron may run before you have an X user session active, so maybe that's the hint. Can you eg. `./ROC-smi/rocm-smi -d 1 --setfan 90 | echo "1\n" >> ./err.log ` on each line just to verify the script is being invoked?

If that's the case (running but crashing because X isn't ready), try with this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/738640/run-script-as-root-immediately-after-login-to-gui

Comment: Hmm, i added that on every line of my script with different numbers and i checked every directory where err.log shoud be created but I found nothing. I checked /etc; /ROC-smi, and teamredminer dir
But i saw one thing when i run script manually. I got that error:

Comment: Start with a MWE then. Let `script.sh` be `#!/bin/bash\necho "Chrontab did work $(date)\n" >> /tmp/err.log` and then in crontab add `@reboot /path/to/script.sh`. Reboot and check if works (it should). also check `grep cron /var/log/syslog`

Comment: ok, Thank you for your big help, decided to go more straighforward like in answer you sent me, i plug in monitor and manually from gui "Startup Applications" add command to run my script with absolute path and everything is working.